# UISlider - draw line / image to the track (bar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have `UISlider` with min and max track colors. I want to draw vertical line (or image) in the middle of the slider track. This line must be there the whole time, only color on top of it will be different (min / max track color).

If I put UIImage on the Slider background, tracks covers it. If I set clear color for tracks, I can see line, but no colors from tracks (obviously). Is there any simple way, how to do this, or I have to override drawRect method for Slider ?

Something like on the slider in image

[image]

Comment: there are dozens of tutorials on creating your own slider subclass. any reason why you are trying to avoid overriding `drawRect`? its not difficult and is way more elegant and less prone to breakage then trying to overlay something external.

Comment: I think that I will do this. Its probably the best way.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control) will be helpful in customising ur slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sort of "ultimate" solution to this type of project is...

http://www.paintcodeapp.com

As @BradAllred pointed out, the fundamental problem here is: **you are trying to avoid drawRect**.

Realistically, you can only achieve your goal here by subclassing UIControl or slider.

As others have mentioned fortunately there are many great tutorials, etc, on doing this -- and it's not hard.

Once again paintcodeapp.com is kind of an "incredible secret" to making iOS apps, enjoy.

Comment: if you mean paintcode, it's an amazing product eh!  enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

add an UIView that is 1 pixel wide and has the height of the Slider and put it over the slider.

Comment: Yes.. that was also one of my thoughts. But this way, I have UIView in front of the slider thumb

Comment: In the slider delegate check when slider is at 50% and make the view invisiblem for everyother % make it visible. This is the only simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CALayer, draw it, (even add an image to it), then add that layer as a sublayer to the Slider's layer.contents.